# Async/future error handling in Dart not working as expected

Tags: dart, dart-async

I've been at this for hours studying the [Futures and Error Handling](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/) section on the Dart page without any luck. Can anyone explain why the code below does not print `All good`?

```
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  try {
    await func1();
  } catch (e) {
    print('All good');
  }
}

Future func1() {
  var completer = new Completer();
  func2().catchError(() => completer.completeError('Noo'));
  return completer.future;
}

Future func2() {
  var completer = new Completer();
  completer.completeError('Noo');
  return completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `func1` the function used as `catchError` parameter must be a subtype of type `(dynamic) => dynamic` regarding the error:

> Unhandled exception:
>
> type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'.

Thus you should use:

```
Future func1() {
  var completer = new Completer();
  func2().catchError((e) => completer.completeError('Noo'));
  return completer.future;
}
```

You don't get any analyzer error because the parameter is typed with `Function`. You can [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new) to know why the type is not a more specific type matching `(dynamic)=>dynamic`

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I thought the code was fine as I got no analyzer warnings. Furthermore, I was confused by the fact that DartPad shows all errors and exceptions as just `Script error` so I thought the code failed because of the `completeError` call in `func2()` but it had nothing to do with that.

Comment: The function type of the `catchError` argument is not more specific because the function accepts both `(dynamic)->dynamic` and `(dynamic, StackTrace)->dynamic`. The most precise type accepting both is `Function`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. One more place where union type could help.